# Best way to combine a permutation of conditional statements

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, combinations

So, I have a series of actions to perform, based on 4 conditional variables - lets say x,y,z & t. Each of these variables have a possible True or False value. So, that is a total of 16 possible permutations. And I need to perform a different action for each permutation.

What is the best way to do this rather than making a huge if-else construct.

Lets see a simplified example. This is how my code would look if I try to contain all the different permutations into a large if-else construct.

```
if (x == True):
    if (y == True):
        if (z == True):
            if (t == True):
                print ("Case 1")
            else:
                print ("Case 2")
        else:
            if (t == True):
                print ("Case 3")
            else:
                print ("Case 4")
    else:
        if (z == True):
            if (t == True):
                print ("Case 5")
            else:
                print ("Case 6")
        else:
            if (t == True):
                print ("Case 7")
            else:
                print ("Case 8")
else:
    if (y == True):
        if (z == True):
            if (t == True):
                print ("Case 9")
            else:
                print ("Case 10")
        else:
            if (t == True):
                print ("Case 11")
            else:
                print ("Case 12")
    else:
        if (z == True):
            if (t == True):
                print ("Case 13")
            else:
                print ("Case 14")
        else:
            if (t == True):
                print ("Case 15")
            else:
                print ("Case 16")
```

Is there any way to simplify this? Obviously, my objective for each case is more complicated than just printing "Case 1".

Comment: Count from 0 to 15 in binary? Your code is equivalent to `print("Case " + str(8*(x==True) + 4*(y==True) + 2*(z==True) + 1*(t == True)))`

Comment: It may be easier to not have it nested and check all 4 values 16 times in one if-else statement.

Comment: Normally it is more appropriate to use `if x:` rather than `if (x == True):`

Comment: @JohnColeman Nice solution. You don't need the '==True' part on every variable though.

Comment: @KaiwenChen -- True, although I think that I have `True` and `False` swapped (looking at OP's listing of cases).

Comment: @JohnColeman *Obviously, my objective for each case is more complicated than just printing "Case 1".*

Comment: @JohnKugelman Of course -- but the cases *do* correspond to numbers in 0-15. One can calculate that number and then branch to the case.

Comment: Consider first whether you actually have 16 independent cases. What you do when `x` is True may not depend on the values of `y` or `z` at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a map of cases to results:

```
cases = { (True,  True,  True,  True):  "Case 1",
      (True,  True,  True,  False): "Case 2",
      (True,  True,  False, True): "Case 3",
      (True,  True,  False, False):"Case 4",
      (True,  False, True,  True): "Case 5",
      (True,  False, True,  False):"Case 6",
      (True,  False, False, True): "Case 7",
      (True,  False, False, False):"Case 8",
      (False, True,  True,  True): "Case 9",
      (False, True,  True,  False):"Case 10",
      (False, True,  False, True): "Case 11",
      (False, True,  False, False):"Case 12",
      (False, False, True,  True): "Case 13",
      (False, False, True,  False):"Case 14",
      (False, False, False, True): "Case 15",
      (False, False, False, False):"Case 16"}

print(cases[(x,y,z,t])
```

If you want to do something else/different for each case, you could add a function to that map.

```
cases = { (True,  True,  True,  True):  foo_func,
      (True,  True,  True,  False): bar_func,
         ...}

result = cases[(x,y,x,t)](*args)
```

You can also use one of the masking solutions to make the code shorter, or if you have too many cases to write out, but for smaller sets of cases, this explicit representation will be clearer and easier to maintain.

Comment: Square brackets and parentheses should be swapped in the last line of code:
`result = cases[(x,y,x,t)](*args)`

Answer (score 2):

You could shove all the values into a tuple and use 16 tuple comparisons.

```
if   (x, y, z, t) == (True,  True,  True,  True):  print("Case 1")
elif (x, y, z, t) == (True,  True,  True,  False): print("Case 2")
elif (x, y, z, t) == (True,  True,  False, True):  print("Case 3")
elif (x, y, z, t) == (True,  True,  False, False): print("Case 4")
elif (x, y, z, t) == (True,  False, True,  True):  print("Case 5")
elif (x, y, z, t) == (True,  False, True,  False): print("Case 6")
elif (x, y, z, t) == (True,  False, False, True):  print("Case 7")
elif (x, y, z, t) == (True,  False, False, False): print("Case 8")
elif (x, y, z, t) == (False, True,  True,  True):  print("Case 9")
elif (x, y, z, t) == (False, True,  True,  False): print("Case 10")
elif (x, y, z, t) == (False, True,  False, True):  print("Case 11")
elif (x, y, z, t) == (False, True,  False, False): print("Case 12")
elif (x, y, z, t) == (False, False, True,  True):  print("Case 13")
elif (x, y, z, t) == (False, False, True,  False): print("Case 14")
elif (x, y, z, t) == (False, False, False, True):  print("Case 15")
elif (x, y, z, t) == (False, False, False, False): print("Case 16")
```

This could be converted into a dict lookup or use clever binary packing tricks, but the advantages here are (a) it's straightforward and readable; (b) there's no need for `lambda`s or functions; and (c) you can put anything into the 16 cases.

Comment: you could save the tuple to a variable first to avoid repeating the lhs that many times...

Answer (score 2):

you could get your case number directly from binary manipulation of your booleans:

```
case = (x^1) << 3 | (y^1) << 2 | (z^1) << 1 | (t^1) + 1
print(f'Case {case}')
```

if you look at [John Kugelman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55422954/4954037) you see that `x, y, z, t` are just the 'bits' of your case number (where `True=0` and `False=1`)... so i construct an `int` setting those bits (and then add `1` because you start counting at `1`).

if the numbering is arbitrary you can simplify that down to `x << 3 | y << 2 | z << 1 | t` and take it from there.

this is easily extensible to a larger number of boolean variables.

then to do something based on the case number i suggest you create a dictionary containing the `case` as key and the function or data or whatever as value. something like:

```
case_functions = {1: func_1, 2: func_2, ...}
res = case_functions(case)(some argument)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a flexible solution that offers scalability and a certain level of simplicity.

Firstly, you'll need to create the methods that will run per output. These are the "complicated" versions of your `print("case X")` statements

```
#Define your method outcomes here...
#Note that this follows a binary layout starting with 
# a + b + c + d = false
def action1():      #binary 0 (a'b'c'd')
    print("case 1")
def action2():      #binary 1 (a'b'c'd)
    print("case 2")
def action3():      #binary 2 (a'b'cd')
   print("case 3")
def action4():      #binary 3 (a'b'cd)
    print("case 4")
def action5():      #binary 4 (a'bc'd')
    print("case 5") #etc...
def action6():
    print("case 6")
def action7():
    print("case 7")
def action8():
    print("case 8")
def action9():
    print("case 9")
def action10():
    print("case 10")
def action11():
    print("case 11")
def action12():
    print("case 12")
def action13():
    print("case 13")
def action14():
    print("case 14")
def action15():
    print("case 15")
def action16():
    print("case 16")
def actionDefault():
    print("Error!")
```

Then, you can easily reference these specific action methods later by creating a method name list and then creating a method to reference the method list when called.

```
import itertools #Generates all permutations
import sys       #Allows us to get the current module

#Returns the index of the actionList we should execute
def evaluateActionIndex(varList): 
    allcombinations = itertools.product([False, True], repeat=len(varList))
    i = 0
    for subset in allcombinations: #for each of the possible combinations...
        if list(subset) == varList: #Check to see if we want to execute this index.
            return i
        i = i + 1                  #Increment the target index
    return -1                      #Execute default method (-1 index)

def performAction(index):
    actionList = [action1.__name__, action2.__name__, action3.__name__, action4.__name__, 
                  action5.__name__, action6.__name__, action7.__name__, action8.__name__,
                  action9.__name__, action10.__name__, action11.__name__, action12.__name__,
                  action13.__name__, action14.__name__, action15.__name__, action16.__name__,
                  actionDefault.__name__]
    method = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], actionList[index])  #Get method by name
    method()                                                    #Execute Method
```

We can perform some action by using:

```
#Mock up some control inputs
a = False
b = True
c = False
d = False
controlVariables = [a, b, c, d] #All Your Control Variables

#Execute control sequence
performAction(evaluateActionIndex(controlVariables))
```

I've tested this and it works effectively. You can add as many control variables as you need to the `controlVariables` list.

Answer (score 1):

That's genious. Bits! Very clean.

I was searching for a solution to this for a long time.

Here's a javascript version:

```
//assuming you have your variables in an array
let q = evaluatedQuery = ["wd:Q82955", "wd:Q212238", "", "wd:Q116"]

//lenght of the binary string
let possibleCases = evaluatedQuery.length
let binaryCase = ""


for (let i = 0; i < possibleCases; i++) {

    // this "!!" makes a value truthy or falsy,
    // and converts that to an integer "!!q[i] ^ 0"

    binaryCase = `${binaryCase}${!!q[i] ^ 0}`

}

//this finds out which of (q*q = 16) cases its gonna be
let parsedBinaryCase = parseInt(binaryCase, 2) + 1

//this converts it to an array for easy handling
let binaryCaseArr = binaryCase.split("")

//this filers out falsy values by taking falsy values index
let boundQueryElements = evaluatedQuery.filter((el, i) => {
    return !binaryCaseArr[i] != !!el ^ 0 
})

console.log(binaryCase) //output: 1101
console.log(parsedBinaryCase) //output: 14
console.log(boundQueryElements) //output: ['wd:Q82955','wd:Q212238','wd:Q116']

//and this is a clean way to handle those 16 cases
//in this example it would go to case 14
switch (parsedBinaryCase) {
    case 1:
        break
    case 2:
        break
    case 3:
        break
    case 4:
        break
    case 5:
        break
    case 6:
        break
    case 7:
        break
    case 8:
        break
    case 9:
        break
    case 10:
        break
    case 11:
        break
    case 12:
        break
    case 13:
        break
    case 14:
     // for (let el in boundQueryElements) {
     // }
        break
    case 15:
        break
    case 16:
        break
    default:
}
```

It, like, 'flattens' the tree structure.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the binary-ness of `True` and `False` values:

```
x = True
y = True
z = True
t = True
total = bin(x + 2 * y + 4 * z + 8 * t)
print(total)
print(int(total, 2))
```

Outputs:

> 0b1111
>
> 15

Whereas

```
x = False
y = True
z = False
t = True
total = bin(x + 2 * y + 4 * z + 8 * t)
print(total)
print(int(total, 2))
```

Yields:

> 0b1010
>
> 10

Now you can easily use the `int(total, 2)` value to determine which case you are dealing with

So you could convert your code to a single level of indents:

```
case = int(total, 2)
if case == 0:
    print('case 0')
elif case == 1:
    print('case 1')
elif case == 2:
    print('case 2')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

When there are this many cases I usually prefer writing helper functions that make the code easier to maintain, e.g.:

```
def compare(xyzt, binaryval):
    boolval = tuple(digit == '1' for digit in binaryval)
    return all(a == b for a, b in zip(xyzt, boolval))
```

then your if statement can be written as:

```
xyzt = (x, y, z, t)
if   compare(xyzt, '1111'): ...
elif compare(xyzt, '1110'): ...
elif compare(xyzt, '1100'): ...
etc.
```

which makes it much easier to verify that you've considered all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a nice place for a registry of handlers. This won't give you the *shortest* code, but I think it gives you code that is easier to read and more maintainable, which is one interpretation of "simpler". I'd do something like this:

### registry.py

```py
handlers = dict()
def register(x, y, z, t):
    if (x, y, z, t) in handlers:
        raise ValueError("Handler already registered for {}/{}/{}/{}".format(
                x, y, z, t))
    def insert(f):
        handlers[(x, y, z, t)] = f
    return insert

def handle(x, y, z, t):
    if (x, y, z, t) not in handlers:
        raise KeyError("No handler registered for {}/{}/{}/{}".format(
                x, y, z, t))
    return handlers[(x, y, z, t)]()
```

### handlers.py

```py
from delegation import register, handle

@register(x=True, y=True, z=False, t=True)
def some_descriptive_name():
    print("hi!")

@register(x=True, y=False, z=True, t=False)
def another_good_name():
    print("Yes hello.")

# etc.
```

### main.py

```py
from handlers import handle

x, y, z, t = True, False, False, True
handle(x, y, z, t)
```

This lets you see exactly the conditions under which each handler will be activated. Separating your handlers into their own functions makes for cleaner testing as well. I've added a check to make sure you're not trying to handle the same conditions more than once and an error message for if a set of conditions isn't handled. It'd be easy to add a check to make sure that *all* cases are handled, too.

If your actions need to make use of variables (besides the four conditionals) you can do that as well; just change the signature and return value of `handle` like so:

```py
def handle(x, y, z, t, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    return handlers[(x, y, z, t)](*args, **kwargs)
```

and, of course, add arguments to the handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on @Reedinationer's answer:

```
# your functions
def f0(): print('case 1')
def f1(): print('case 2')
def f2(): print('case 3')
#.
#.
def f15(): print('case 16')

list_of_functions = [f0, f1, f2] # assuming there are 16 functions in total

x = False
y = False
z = False
t = False
total = bin(x + 2 * y + 4 * z + 8 * t)
index = int(total, 2)

list_of_functions[index]() # will print('case 1')
```

Tested on python 2.7 and 3.7