# SPARQL - How to Filter if a property exists, otherwise add as is?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to select people, whose date of birth ( wdt:P569 ) is above 1920, if they have a date of birth and add everybody else who don't have a date of birth.

```
SELECT ?politician
WHERE {

VALUES ?occupations {wd:Q193391 wd:Q116}

?politician wdt:P106  ?occupations .
OPTIONAL {
  ?politician wdt:P569 ?date .
  FILTER (year(?date) > 1920)
}

MINUS {?politician wdt:P102 ?o }
FILTER NOT EXISTS {?politician wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20 ?o }

}
```

It probably can be solved using -> OPTIONAL(FILTER(BIND(IF(BOUND())))).. But I can't figure it out.

Comment: `SELECT ?politician ?date
WHERE {

VALUES ?occupations {wd:Q193391 wd:Q116}

?politician wdt:P106  ?occupations .
  OPTIONAL {?politician wdt:P569 ?date .}
  
  FILTER (!bound(?date) || year(?date) > 1920)



}`

Comment: Thank you! You saved my week! To what does "!bound(?date)" evaluate in both cases? I imagine it evaluates to false in one of two cases. In that case - what does FILTER( false ) evaluate to? Filter(false) is the same as " "?

Comment: `!bound(?date)` covers the case when there is no date, because due to `OPTIONAL` this might be unbound, i.e. there is no binding for the variable `?date`. Regarding `FILTER(false)`, not sure what you mean but this just leads to no binding then. You could also rewrite the filter to e.g. `FILTER(NOT EXISTS {?politician wdt:P569 ?date .} || EXISTS {?politician wdt:P569 ?date . FILTER (year(?date) > 1920)})` and omit the OPTIONAL if you don't need the date. Indeed more verbose and mostly less efficient, so I'd go with my first suggestion.

Comment: So it would be correct to say: when a query executes, the `OPTIONAL` parameter's job is to "initialize" A.K.A. `BIND` a variable. `FILTER(!BOUND(?date)||year(?date)>1920)` is saying - add to results all the matches, where `?date` variable was not "initialized" or if it was "initialized" add to results all matches where `year(?date) > 1920)}` filter evaluates to true. (is there a reason you chose to post the answer in comments?)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ?politician
WHERE {

VALUES ?occupations {wd:Q82955 wd:Q212238 wd:Q193391 wd:Q116}

?politician wdt:P106  ?occupations .
OPTIONAL {?politician wdt:P569 ?date .}
  FILTER (!bound(?date) || year(?date) > 1920) 

MINUS {?politician wdt:P102 ?o }
FILTER NOT EXISTS {?politician wdt:P570|wdt:P509|wdt:P20 ?o }

}
```

Thank you AKSW!

the `OPTIONAL` parameter's job is to "initialize" A.K.A. `BIND` a variable.

The `FILTER( !BOUND(?date) || year(?date)>1920 )` is saying - add to results all the matches, where `?date` variable was not "initialized" or if it was "initialized" - add all the matches where `year(?date) > 1920` filter evaluates to true.

and while I'm on it:

`VALUES ?occupations {wd:Q82955 wd:Q212238 wd:Q193391 wd:Q116}` is javascript's equivalent of saying `var x = (a || b || c || d)`. 
[it's more like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59998256/11078199)
If any of those properties match, then `?occupatoins` becomes bound as well.
Grouping your properties into `VALUES` makes the query more efficient and there's less of a chance it will time out.

The `MINUS` and `FILTER NOT EXISTS` for any practical reason can be considered identical. (they are not in edge cases)
Both of them look, if the match at hand (at that point of the execution) contain any of the listed properties "wd:P570, wd:P58, ..". But unlike `VALUES` the evaluation context is `|` OR, not of ANY.

I used both `MINU` and `FILTER NOT EXISTS` because using just one of them made the query time out.

(it might have become more efficient, because "wdt:102" produces by far the most matches, leaving too big of a chunk for the following operators to sort through)